# C shell script for gcc compiler

Tags: c, windows, shell, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to make a script for testing my c program but I could not figure out why it does not work
I tested it with a easy code so that I am sure that the problem is not because of the C file.

My C Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
printf("Hello World\n");
return 0;
}
```

And my Shell Script is:

```
gcc -o main main.c
echo "Hello world"
```

If I execute the script I get the error message on my console

```
: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated
```

This is the Error I get if I want to execute the script

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP6Qr.jpg

In the image you can see my problem 
If I compile the C file “per hand” it has no problem but if I execute the script which contains the same statement it does not work.
If I just want to compile and only write the command for compiling in my script it works but as soon as I ad an echo or any other command it will not work.

I am using an Ubuntu Shell under Windows.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: you wrote your script with a Windows-only editor such as Notepad, so it used Windows newlines (`\r\n` AKA `CRLF`). `bash` passes `main.c\r` as argument to gcc, which cannot find it. Printing out the error, the terminal interpret `\r` as carriage return character, so, it goes in column 1 and prints the rest of the message, which results in the bizarre thing you are seeing.

You can check if this is the case by running `dos2unix` over your script, if now it works correctly it's as I suspected.

Solution: use a more serious editor and/or make sure it writes Unix newlines (plain `\n`, AKA `LF`).

Comment: Thank you for your help
I tried the vi editor and it worked perfectly 
Thank you very much

Comment: TBH, as much as I love vi and despise any editor that doesn't have vi keybindings, there are a lot of less hardcore alternatives that support Unix line endings... :-) Pretty much anything besides notepad do (e.g. Notepad++ is a popular alternative and does support Unix line endings). Just make sure to check the corresponding option when first saving the file.

Comment: Thank you very much this helps a beginner like myself a lot the vi editor is surely a great editor but for a beginner like me it was very overwhelming and Notepad++ suits my needs perfect thanks for the advise :)